# Can a tar file be efficiently randomly edited?

Tags: file, tar, archive

Is there a way to modify an individual file within a tar file without having to rewrite the entire archive? I recognize this would probably result in fragmentation.

Is there any other archive format that does this?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should only ask exactly one question on StackOverflow. If you truly want to do frequent writes to the "archive", then you might be better off simply creating a large file, formatting it with some file system of your choice and then mounting it:

```sh
truncate -s $(( 512*1024*1024 )) 512MiB-filesystem.ext4
mkfs.ext4 512MiB-filesystem.ext4
sudo mount -o loop 512MiB-filesystem.ext4 mountpoint
sudo chmod a+w mountpoint/
echo foo > mountpoint/bar
sudo umount mountpoint
```

As for your question about TAR. It is possible and a fun exercise but it might lack the tools that actually implement this. First off, TAR is a very simple file format, it consists of 512 B blocks that can either contain metadata or actual file contents simply copied from the original file without any compression.

A TAR can actually contain multiple files for the same path and by convention, the last duplicate path wins. This means, in order to "modify" a file, you can simply append a newer version of that file to the TAR:

```
tar --append --file archive.tar modified-file
```

This should be fast, but it would grow the archive with every file change, so it should be used sparingly.

If you want even more in-place modifications, they should be possible but there is no tooling yet for that as far as I know. I would like to implement that into [ratarmount](https://github.com/mxmlnkn/ratarmount) but I'm not sure when I'll get to it.

File system operations and how to implement them:

- **Modifying a file:**

  - *File size is constant:* As long as the file size does not change, we could simply change the file inside the TAR if we know the offset for the file contents in the TAR archive, which ratarmount does have stored in an SQLite database.
  - *File size is quasi constant:* Actually, the file size might even change by up to 511 B and it still would be possible to simply update the file inside the TAR as long as it doesn't change the number of required TAR blocks (512 B). This would also require updating the file size in the TAR metadata block and updating the checksum of that metadata block, though.
  - *Required TAR blocks shrink:* If the required TAR blocks become fewer than before, then it still would be rather easy to modify the TAR on the fly as outlined above. But we would have to somehow format the unused blocks. We could simply fill them with zeros, but in this case, we would have to call tar with the `--ignore-zeros` option to still get a valid tar. Without that, all files after that position would suddenly appear lost, so it might be unsuited in some circumstances. But we could also simply fill the empty blocks with dummy data, e.g., a directory metadata entry for the `/` (root) folder. As long as it contains the same metadata as the actual root folder, it basically is a no-op. It might even be possible to create dummy metadata blocks for invalid paths like `.` or `..` to effectively create blocks that are ignored even without the `--ignore-zeros` option.
  - *Required TAR blocks grow:` This is the most difficult case. If there is simply no space to put the added data to the file, then we might have to delete it and move it to the end of the file (if it isn't already at the end). Removing the file without rewriting everything else in the TAR would be implemented as mentioned above by either filling the parts with zeros or dummy metadata blocks. At this point, however, we could implement defragmentation techniques, e.g., by keeping track of all empty / dummy blocks in the TAR and looking for fitting places. Or if we want to append 1 KiB to a 1 GiB file, then it might avoid fragmentation better if we move a small file right after the 1 GiB file to the end of the TAR to make space for the 1 KiB to append.
- **Modifying file metadata:**

  - *In General*: In general, metadata can be changed by simply changing it in the metadata block and updating the block checksum. This does not require rewriting anything else in the archive
  - *Removals:* This is basically the same as file modifications for shrinking block counts. Simply overwrite the space for this file entry with zeros or dummy blocks and maybe keep track of it for writing files into this space at a later time.
  - *Renames:* Renames can actually be more tricky than one might think. In most cases, it can also simply be updated, however, there are two problematic cases:

    - *The file name becomes too long:* If the file name becomes too long, then the GNU long name extension will allocate further blocks right after the TAR metadata block, which will contain the very long filename. This however would require one more block, which might require moving around blocks inside the TAR as outlined for file modifications
    - *There are file name collisions:* If the target path already exists, then simply updating the metadata might not suffice depending on the order the files appear in the TAR. The last one with the same path wins. This might be easy to circumvent by simply forbidding to move to an existing path or by calling remove on the existing file beforehand.
    - *Create:* This is simple. Simply append the file to the end of the archive. If implemented manually, then we might have to find the actual end of the data because TAR archives have at least 2 (often more) zero-byte blocks after the last valid data and simply appending new files after those zero blocks would require the `--ignore-zero-bytes` option.